# How to fire an event in a parent thread in vb.net from a child thread (no UI)

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, events, mailkit

Would request help with the following. Thanks in advance.

I am trying to make a mail-client using MailKit Imap client in vb.Net. The Mailkit Imap client is in Idle mode, when a new mail arrives, it raises an event which is in its own thread.

Now when I want to store these emails in a database, I want to do that processing not in that thread but in my parent class's thread. How do I accomplish that? I know that InvokeRequired and Invoke can be done on Form Controls, but this is not a form, it's a class.

Eg: Code is :

My ImapMonitor class has an event as such:

```
Class ImapMonitor

Private Sub rFolder_MessageArrived(sender as object, e as MailkitMessagesArrivedEventArgs) handles rfolder.MessagesArrived
   RaiseEvent NewMessages(param1,param2)
End Sub

End Class

Class MailChecker
'My Main class which creates an object of ImapMonitor class goes :

Dim withevents iMonitor as ImapMonitor

Private Sub iMonitor_NewMessages(param1,param2) handles ImapMonitor.NewMessages 'this event is not in MailCheckers thread
 'Retrieve the messages and store them in DB
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the handler manually using `AddHanlder`

Using a simple example. A class that is raising events:

```
Public Class ClassDoingWork
    Public Event NewMessage()

    Public Sub DoWork()
        RaiseEvent NewMessage()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And a class that uses this worker class, calling `DoWork` on a new thread and subscribing to the `NewMessage` event:

```
Public Class ClassMonitoringThread
    Public Sub New()
        Dim workerThread As New ClassDoingWork
        AddHandler workerThread.NewMessage, AddressOf NewMessageEvent
        Dim thr As New Thread(Sub() workerThread.DoWork())
        thr.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub NewMessageEvent()
        MessageBox.Show("New Message")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: dosen't seem to help, the event still fires in the Worker's thread. :(

Comment: yes - the event will fire in the workers thread, but you are handling it in the monitoring thread

Comment: Thanks .. My example above already does that, doesn't it ? or am i missing something.?